# Averaging aggregated(SUM) values in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to Average aggregated(SUM) values, but my expression keeps doing weighted averages over the whole data set.

Table Structure

```
REGION  SITE_ID  MONTH  QUANTITY
A       1        01     5
A       1        02     6
A       2        01     4
B       3        01     10
B       3        02     12
```

Expression

```
Avg(
    Sum([quantity]) over (All([region]))/
    UniqueCount([site_id]) over (All([region]))/ 
    UniqueCount([month]) over (All([region]))
) over (All([region]))
```

To Clarify, I want to average A and B's Monthly Qty per Site

But I keep getting total qty divided by total no of site_ids divided by months

Comment: You don't have any SITE_ID that belong to both regions. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes they are unique

Comment: So you really want to average A and B's monthly quantity, that is all of A for month 1 and all of B for month 1, correct? Since site is unique to each region, it shouldn't play in this formula.

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to get at..

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on where you are going to use it and what the **REAL** data looks like. This should get you started. Insert this calculated column.

```
SUM([QUANTITY]) OVER (Intersect([REGION],[MONTH])) / UniqueCount([REGION]) AS [AvgOverRegionByMonth]
```

This could be inaccurate depending on how the rest of your data looks like. You can also accomplish this in a cross table. The expressions for the Sum and Avg on the example below are as follows:

```
Sum([QUANTITY]) as [Sum], Sum([QUANTITY]) / Count([REGION]) as [Average]
```

[image: CrossTable]

---

**EDIT**

In order to ONLY get the average over the months, use this forumla:

```
AVG([QUANTITY]) OVER ([MONTH]) as [AvgOverMonth]
```

Here is what your data will look like:

[image: Average Over Month]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Ill have a go at the office tmrw mornig

Comment: No worries. Good luck, let me know if it doesn't fit your true data, and if it does of course!

Comment: I actually want a single average value of A and B regions, not the average of individual regions

Comment: Ok I'll fix it in the morning.  Sorry you are in ROK and I'm in America, opposite sides of the world hahaha.